# Filtering country to apply different stopwords

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataset

```
                                   Text
country     file                          
US          file_US                The Dish: Lidia Bastianich shares Italian recipes ... - CBS News
            file_US                Blog - Tasty Yummies
            file_US                Acne Alternative Remedies: Manuka Honey, Tea Tree Oil ...
            file_US                Looking back at 10 years of Downtown Arts | Times Leader 

IT          filename_IT            Tornando indietro a ...
            filename_IT            Questo locale è molto consigliato per le famiglie
                                                                            ...                                 
            filename_IT            Ci si chiede dove poter andare a mangiare una pizza  Melanzana Capriccia ...
            filename_IT            Ideale per chi ama mangiare vegano
```

with country and file *indices*.
I want to apply a function which remove stopwords based on the value of the index:

```
def removing(sent):
    
    if df.loc['US','UK']:
        stop_words = stopwords.words('english')
    if df.loc['ES']:
        stop_words = stopwords.words('spanish')    
    
# (and so on)
                      
    c_text = []

    for i in sent.lower().split():
        if i not in stop_words:
            c_text.append(i)

    return(' '.join(c_text))

df['New_Column'] = df['Text'].astype(str)
df['New_Column'] = df['New_Column'].apply(removing)
```

Unfortunately I am getting this error:

> ----> 6     if df.loc['US']:
> 7         stop_words = stopwords.words('english')
> 8     if df.loc['ES']:
>
> /anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in
> **nonzero**(self)    1477     def **nonzero**(self):    1478         raise ValueError(
> -> 1479             f"The truth value of a {type(self).**name**} is ambiguous. "    1480             "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(),
> a.any() or a.all()."    1481         )
>
> ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
> a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

and I am still not understanding how to fix it. Can you please tell me how I can run the code without getting the error?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o)

Comment: Some people just leave just downvote my answer without left a single word , so I will remove it. Hope you get the Idea not use for loop when you have panda and numpy

Comment: it was not me, @YOBEN_S. I have just open stackoverflow

Comment: @still_learning I know , no problem , hope you already get the method np.where ~

Comment: @AMC, I provided an example of sentences that I would need to clean. For each country I have 10 similar sentences. Country is an index. I have already seen that question but unfortunately I have still not completely understood how to change accordingly my code

Comment: @YOBEN_S, unfortunately I am not getting how to fix the issue looking at the suggested answer by AMC

Comment: @still_learning 1st that is not his answer , 2nd your problem is different from what he linked

Comment: @YOBEN_S _2nd your problem is different from what he linked_ Can you elaborate? I thought they were quite similar.

Comment: unfortunately I have not fixed my issue yet, even after the question mentioned by AMC. If you have any advice to give me or a solution, I would greatly appreciate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#Assuming you have imported all the required libraries
#Make a dictionary with country code & language
lang={'UK':'english','US':'english','ES':'spanish'}
#assuming your dataframe as df
for index,row in df.iterrows():
   df.loc[index,'TEXT']=' '.join([word for word in str(row['TEXT']).split(' ') if word not in stopwords.words(lang[index])])
```

Updated answer:

```
 import pandas as pd
 import numpy as np
 import nltk
 from nltk.corpus import stopwords
 ind=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['ind','ind','ind','ind','aus','aus','aus','aus'], ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8']])
 df=pd.DataFrame(['he is boy','he is boy','he is boy','he is boy','he is boy','he is boy','he is boy','he is boy'],index=ind,columns=['text'])
 lang={'ind':'spanish','aus':'english'}
 for index,row in df.iterrows():
       df.at[(index[0],index[1]),'text']=' '.join([word for word in str(row['text']).split(' ') if word not in stopwords.words(lang[index[0]])])
```

Before running loop:

[image]

After running loop:

[image]

Do try to take reference from the example I used!!

Comment: Thank you Mehul Gupta. I have a problem to apply your code since there is another index column in my dataset. How can I select only Country? I am receiving this message: `KeyError: ('UK', 'original+key')`

Comment: Can you tell me how many levels of the index are there in the dataset? Attaching a screenshot can be helpful

Comment: I have tried to attach the screenshot, but I am having problem to save the changes. There are two indices: `country` and `name`.  (I will keep trying to update the question with the screenshot... I hope it may be fixed soon)

Comment: that is ['country','name'] is your index. Right? If so, keep everything as it is & change index to index[0] in stopwords.words() !! if this works, do let me know, I will update my answer as well

Comment: Hi @Mehul Gupta, sorry for my late reply. I have got the following error: after changing as you suggested in stopwords: `stopwords.words(lang[index[0]])])`
->
`TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your data? using df.head()

Comment: I updated the dataset to show how my data looks like. Please let me know if it is better and/or if you have any further questions. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Updated my answer & tried using a similar example as your data. Do inform if this works!!

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can use `numpy.where()`:

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy import where

df = pd.DataFrame(...)

# Remove the english stopwords from the english sentences
c = ['US','UK']
for p in c:
    stop_words = stopwords.words('english')
    for w in stop_words:
        df['Text'] = where(df['country'] == p, # If the country is english
                              df['Text'].str.replace(w,''), # Replace each stopword in each sentence with blank
                              df['Text'])


# Remove the spanish stopwords from the spanish sentences
stop_words = stopwords.words('spanish')
for w in stop_words:
    df['Text'] = where(df['country'] == 'ES', # If the country is spanish
                          df['Text'].str.replace(w,''), # Replace each stopword in each sentence with blank
                          df['Text'])
```

Comment: @still_learning can you show me the dataframe's base?

Comment: @still_learning You can also try changing `df['country']` to `df.index`.

Comment: I updated the dataset within the question. It looks like as shown there :) I just edited the Text column to avoid confusion. When you say "change `df['country']` to `df.index`", how can I select country index?

Comment: @still_learning I mean the base of the dataframe, like `pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':[4,5,6]})`

Comment: can you provide a screenshot of it?

Comment: Try changing all the `df['country']` to `df[['country']]`.

Comment: If that doesn't work, change `df['country']` to `df['path']`.

Comment: When I change `df['country']` to `df[['country']]` (or to path) I get this error: `KeyError: "None of [Index(['country'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"`

Comment: Is the dataset in the very top generated by pandas, or is that a copy paste from the csv?

Comment: Is the dataset in the very top generated by pandas?

Comment: I think there is a problem with the loop as it replicates the same text through all the rows

Comment: I tested it on a dummy dataframe, and it worked fine.

Comment: Maybe I am doing something wrong, but I have just copied the code you suggested, after transforming the index to a column in the original dataset. Could you please provide an example of that?

Answer (score -1):

define your function with

```
thecountry = x["Country"]
if thecountry == "UK" or thecountry=="US"
x["text"] = remove_stopwords("English")
```

...
(etc)

And then `df["filtered"] = df.apply(removing, axis=1)`

Comment: No, but just `reset_index()` first, you can `set_index("Country")` later.